Sound audio is not playing on iOs device when audio is recorded on Android
I have a Flutter chat app where users record an audio and save it to Firebase Storage.  Permissions are fine. I am using just_audio: ^0.9.39 to play the audio files.
When I follow the following path, I don't run into problems:

Save an audio to Firebase Storage using iOS device
Play the audio on Android device

However, when I follow the following path, I run into exception:

Save an audio to Firebase Storage using Android device
Play the audio on iOS device

This is the exception that I am getting:
Cannot Open
AudioPlayer._load (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:875:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
  AudioPlayer._setPlatformActive.setPlatform (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1501:28)
<asynchronous suspension>

Here is how I get player
      final player = AudioPlayer();
      final audioSource = LockCachingAudioSource(Uri.parse(url));
      player.setAudioSource(audioSource, preload: true);

This is how I play the audio
player.play();

This is the output of Flutter doctor
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-x64, locale en-AE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.90.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)            
[✓] Network resources

Any idea why this can be happening? It seams to me that the Android saved audio file is somehow no readable by iOS.  I am not sure why. Any ideas?
